# SSRS - Group By Multiple Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to group by specific values of a field.  I have project information data populating, and I would like to group on electoral area field.

However, I would like to group the values together in a specific way.  For example:

***If the values are:***

District of Invermere, 
City of Cranbrook, 
Town of Creston

**Then group those projects in a group called "EAST"**

***If the values are:***

Village of Valemount, 
Village of New Denver, 
Village of Kaslo

**Then group those projects in a group called "WEST"**

**Everything else  group in "BASIN".**

So, far I have created a group and in the group properties I have put an expression in the **"Group on"** field:

```
**=iif(Fields!cbt_electoralareaidname.Value = "District of Invermere" OR "City of Cranbrook" , "EAST" ,(iif(Fields!cbt_electoralareaidname.Value = "RDCK Area F" OR "Town of Creston", "WEST", "BASINWIDE")))**
```

But nothing is working... I know I am overthinking this, please HELP!

**UPDATE**

The following is sample data:

- Project Name
- Project Description
- Location
- Electoral Area

It is retrieved and the layout is currently like this:

[image: Project Details]

I also have the field Electoral Area, and that is the field I want to SORT/GROUP the data on but not using the SQL query because I do not want to aggregate, I want the details as they are and create Row Groups.  For the example below, I just want it to look like below:

[image: Sorted By]

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result? `group by` typically implies aggregation, it's not clear if you want rows within a 'group' of values such as the two you stated to be consolidated in some way or just replaced on each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Select ...
From ..
GROUP by 
case 
when city in ("city1","city2",...) then "west" 
When city in (...) Then "east"
Else "other"
End
```

If you want to generate an extra field so you can group by later:

```
Select ..., 
case 
when city in ("city1","city2",...) then "west" 
When city in (...) Then "east"
Else "Basin"
End AS region
From ..
```

If you have many citys to define and the case ... end is out of control, you can create a table mapping each city to some region and do a join:

Comment: HI All, I should be a bit more clear, I do not want the SQL query to do the grouping.  I have created a "Row  Group" in the SSRS report on the electoral area.  This sorts it by the values returned in the electoral area field of my dataset.  But now I want to group that data set by the values that are selected.  I will update my original question with screen shots as well.

Comment: Your second generate a field to group by might achieve what I am looking for.  I can try it out and let you know, if you have any other suggestions based on my edits above, please let me know.  Thank you very much for your help, it is very appreciated!

Comment: This works amazing, thank you so much for the help!  I am marking this second query as the answer, I am indebted to you Tim3880! Thank you :)

Comment: The second part of this answer helped me to add an additional column to my own dataset to get a total on a subgroup in that dataset. Well done, @Tim3880 !